# results of Iterative and recursion benchmark of QuickSort should looks like this?

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I just create benchmark to compare speed of two implementation of Quick sort.
Iterative and recursion.

I expected than recursive will be slower, but I got that plot (blue is rec):

[image]

It's possible that recursion is faster? Maybe I just do some mistake in my code?

Just in case I pase my code.

```
    import time
import random
import sys


arrayList = []
arr = [random.randint(1,15000) for _ in range(1000)]

numbersList = [100000, 300000, 500000, 900000, 1000000, 1500000]
numbersForBenchmark = []
for i in range(len(numbersList)):
    arr = [random.randint(1,15000) for _ in range(numbersList[i])]
    numbersForBenchmark.append(arr)

print(numbersForBenchmark)
recursionTimeArray = []
iterationTimeArray = []


arrRe = arr
arrIt = arr



def partition(lst, start, end):
    pos = start

    for i in range(start, end):
        if lst[i] < lst[end]:             # in your version it always goes from 0
            lst[i],lst[pos] = lst[pos],lst[i]
            pos += 1

    lst[pos],lst[end] = lst[end],lst[pos] # you forgot to put the pivot
                                          # back in its place
    return pos

def quick_sort_recursive(lst, start, end):
    if start < end:                       # this is enough to end recursion
        pos = partition(lst, start, end)
        quick_sort_recursive(lst, start, pos - 1)
        quick_sort_recursive(lst, pos + 1, end)
        #print(lst)

def iter(arr,l,h):
    i = ( l - 1 )
    x = arr[h]

    for j in range(l , h):
        if   arr[j] <= x:

            # increment index of smaller element
            i = i+1
            arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i]

    arr[i+1],arr[h] = arr[h],arr[i+1]
    return (i+1)

def quickSortIterative(arr,l,h):
    size = h - l + 1
    stack = [0] * (size)

    top = -1

    top = top + 1
    stack[top] = l
    top = top + 1
    stack[top] = h

    while top >= 0:

        # Pop h and l
        h = stack[top]
        top = top - 1
        l = stack[top]
        top = top - 1

        p = iter( arr, l, h )

        if p-1 > l:
            top = top + 1
            stack[top] = l
            top = top + 1
            stack[top] = p - 1

        if p+1 < h:
            top = top + 1
            stack[top] = p + 1
            top = top + 1
            stack[top] = h


for i in range(len(numbersForBenchmark)):
    arrRe = numbersForBenchmark[i][:]
    arrIt = numbersForBenchmark[i][:]

    n = len(arrIt)
    start = time.time()
    quickSortIterative(arrIt, 0, n-1)
    end = time.time()
    ITime = end - start
    iterationTimeArray.append(ITime)


    try:
        n = len(arrRe)
        start = time.time()
        quick_sort_recursive(arrRe,0,n-1)
        end = time.time()
        rekTime = end - start
        recursionTimeArray.append(rekTime)
    except RecursionError as re:
        print('Sorry but this maze solver was not able to finish '
              'analyzing the maze: {}'.format(re.args[0]))


print("REK time", recursionTimeArray)
print("ITER TIME", iterationTimeArray)



# evenly sampled time at 200ms intervals
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([10,100,500,1000,5000,8000 ], recursionTimeArray,[10,100,500,1000,5000,8000], iterationTimeArray)
plt.show()
```

The plots look OK, but I expected a completely different result. Hence my doubts about the results.

Comment: Don't use `time.time()` to measure the running time; at least use `perf_counter`, but better to use `timeit`. The graph you showed seems to have different values of `n` than the list lengths you are measuring the times with, and the time axis is not labelled with units (are these seconds, milliseconds, ?). Also, your code has some comments like *"you forgot to ..."* which look like feedback somebody has given you saying that your code is not correct; and there is an error message saying something about a maze. Is the code posted here definitely correct?

Comment: Since python is an interpretive language, there is significant overhead and Python is not ideal for benchmarking algorithms, such as a case where a normally faster algorithm involves more lines of low level code and less usage of built in features.